# Passing TFIDF Feature Vector to a SGDClassifier from sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [1, 1], [2, 1]])
Y = np.array(['C++', 'C#', 'java','python'])
clf = linear_model.SGDClassifier()
clf.fit(X, Y)
print (clf.predict([[1.7, 0.7]]))
#python
```

I am trying to predict the values from arrays Y by giving a test case and training it on a training data which is **X**, Now my problem is that, I want to change the training set **X** to **TF-IDF Feature Vectors**, so how can that be possible?
Vaguely, I want to do something like this

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
X = np.array_str([['abcd', 'efgh'], ['qwert', 'yuiop'], ['xyz','abc'],['opi', 'iop']])
Y = np.array(['C++', 'C#', 'java','python'])
clf = linear_model.SGDClassifier()
clf.fit(X, Y)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look into the [TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) in `scikit-learn`.
I'll presume that **X** is a list of texts to be classified.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(X)
```

And then use the `X_train` as the new **X** to train you classifier on.

```
clf = linear_model.SGDClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, Y)
```